# ALT for img in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi if nearly finished my site and am just wondering on how to add alt  for images in CSS heres my CSS

```
float: left;
width: 490px;
height: 350px;
padding: 0px 0x 0 0px;
font: 11px arial;
line-height: 16px;
min-height: 680px;
padding-left:3;
background:url(images/postcard.png) no-repeat;
text-align: inherit;
vertical-align:top;
```

the postcard has the address Wrote on it like hand writing done in photoshop ,how do i add the Alt of the address to the css ?

Comment: Any reason you are using css for the image and not a standard img tag? John is right, you can't add it in css, and there are some people who feel pretty strongly about using css for non-presentational stuff on sites, check this out: http://www.wait-till-i.com/2009/02/25/so-how-do-you-add-alternative-text-to-background-images/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add Alternative text on your code you need to put it on the HTML MarkUp:

```
<img alt="text here" />
```

if you need dinamyc text use a server side code as php or asp.net:

php:

```
<img alt="<?php getTextFunction(); ?>" />
```

asp.net:

```
<img alt="<% getTextFunction(); %>" />
```

obviusly you need to make a function to get a different alt text for each image.

Regards.

Answer (score 7):

ALT is an HTML attribute. You can't add it using CSS. You'll have to edit your HTML